# PHP shell_exec returns empty when using schtasks

Tags: php, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using PHP to query a scheduled task to see if it is accessible: `shell_exec('schtasks /query /tn "Folder\Task Name"')`.
This returns the task details on multiple servers as it should, however on one in particular, the result is empty.

When running the same task in Powershell, as the same user, it also works fine.

When running `shell_exec('whoami')` from PHP it returns my user as expected.

I'm convinced this is a permissions issue, however the user appears to have the appropriate permissions such as 'run as batch job'. The server is a domain controller. Anyone have any ideas of what I am missing please?

Comment: Try to append `2>&1` at the end of the command to redirect the error messages to the standard output, and check the error message you are getting

Comment: Thanks @HTMHell, finally got back on to the server - it says "Access is denied."